# Rails Sunspot Solr search is not working when there is less than 3 chars

Tags: sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

When I search for "beer" then I got results, but when I search for "bee" i am not getting any results. I can not search for any word which is shorter than 4 chars. Is there a way to make this possible?!

Answer (score 0):

Check your SOLR config `conf/schema.xml` and configurate the settings to your demands. After changes rebuild your index and try again.

It is probably this part, but you have to "play" with the settings.

Try this config as example:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">

  <analyzer type="index">
          <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.PhoneticFilterFactory" encoder="DoubleMetaphone" inject="true"/>

          <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                  generateWordParts="1"
                  generateNumberParts="0"
                  catenateWords="1"
                  catenateNumbers="1"
                  catenateAll="1"
                  splitOnNumerics="0"
                  splitOnCaseChange="1"
                  preserveOriginal="1" />
          <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
          <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                  ignoreCase="true"
                  words="stopwords.txt"
                  enablePositionIncrements="true" />
          <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="German2" protected="protwords.txt"/>
          <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="42" /> 
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
          <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                  ignoreCase="true"
                  words="stopwords.txt"
                  enablePositionIncrements="true" />
          <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="German2" protected="protwords.txt"/>
          <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>

</fieldType>
```

Comment: Any example how to change conf/schema.xml ? What should I change?! I tried 
`<analyzer type="index">
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2"  maxGramSize="30" />
 </analyzer>
 <analyzer type="query">
    <filter class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
</analyzer>
` but that did not work

Comment: i added a full example for the part, modify your config, rebuild index and try.